# How can I reset CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to make a circle and animate it. When I click the button, I want to restart this animation from the same StartPoint. When I click the button I should stop, clear the image and start it again. 
I'm trying with the code below, but it's not working.

```
-(IBAction)MakeCircle:(id)sender{

    // Make a circular shape
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];    
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                            cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

    // Positioning
    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius,
                                  CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);

    // Configure color and linewidth
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 10;

     // Add to parent layer
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];

    // Configure animation
    //CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 5.0; 
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0; 
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    // Add the animation
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];


}

//Stop, "clean"screen and start again

-(IBAction)ButtonStopClearStart:(id)sender{

    circle.speed = 0.0;
    [circle removeAnimationForKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
    [self MakeCircle:(sender)];
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating CAShapeLayer each time for each animation, create it once in viewDidLoad and then simply addAnimation to it the same way you do. When fromValue is specified on animation that you schedule, it will reset animation and start over.

Comment: Now I got the same issue.

Comment: But I am not able to understand @Andy suggestion , It would have been great to post a detailed answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your animation looks something like this...

```
func runTimerMaskAnimation(duration: CFTimeInterval, fromValue : Double){

       ...
             let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: circleBounds, cornerRadius: 
             circleBounds.size.width * 0.5)
             maskLayer?.path = path.reversing().cgPath
             maskLayer?.strokeEnd = 0
    
             parentCALayer.mask = maskLayer
    
             let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
             animation.duration = duration
             animation.fromValue = fromValue
             animation.toValue = 0.0
             maskLayer?.add(animation!, forKey: "strokeEnd")
}
```

If I wanted to restart my timer from the original position I would remove the animation, remove the maskLayer and then run the animation again.

```
 maskLayer?.removeAnimation(forKey: "strokeEnd")
 maskLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
 runTimerMaskAnimation(duration: 15, fromValue : 1)
```